# Use line's 'folded state' in a mapping, so it's `zc` closing but `zv` opening?

Tags: key-bindings, folding

When I'm opening a fold, I would say 100% of the time the behaviour I want is `zv` - open all folds covering the current line, so that I can actually see it.

But `zv` won't close a fold.

How can I use the line's current state of being folded or not folded in a normal mode mapping so that I can have a `za` (toggle fold) but with my desired `zv` behaviour on opening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try overriding the default `za` functionality with this mapping:

```
:nnoremap <expr> za foldclosed(".") == -1 ? 'zc' : 'zv'
```

It uses the [`foldclosed()`](https://www.vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#foldclosed%28%29) function within an [expression mapping](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-expression) to check if the cursor is on a closed fold, mapping to `zc` if it's not, and `zv` if it is.

Comment: Thanks - though `:verbose nnoremap <space>` returns `n  <Space>     * za foldclosed(".") == -1 ? 'zc' : 'zv'`, but its behaviour on a fold (i.e. `:echo foldclosed(".")` prints *not* `-1`) matches `zo`; not `zv`. (i.e. it only opens the first fold.) Any idea what I've missed?

Comment: @OJFord where did `<space>` come from???

Comment: @OJFord I interpreted your question as wanting the mapping to be triggered by `za`. If you want it to be `<Space>` instead of `za`, you need to replace the `za` in my mapping with `<Space>`: `nnoremap <expr> <Space> foldclosed(".") == -1 ? 'zc' : 'zv'` I’m not sure exactly what you typed, but the output you’ve pasted in your comment looks wrong.

Comment: Oh, what an idiot I am :) - it was late... is that any exuse? Many thanks, `<expr>` is new to me so I expect that'll come in handy again.

Comment: @OJFord I should've explained the mapping more when I first wrote it! I've clarified my answer a little, now.